# Use uC hysteresis to evaluate signal

Tags: microcontroller

I have a micro controller (uC) with 1.8V supply and no integrated ADC.
This uC must monitor one signal, and check if it is currently 5V or below 4.2V.

I then need to be able to trigger interrupts based on the value, by sensing HIGH and LOW:

```
LOW for <4.2V
HIGH for 5V
```

Is using the a voltage divider + uC evaluation hysteresis too risky?

Thanks

Comment: Why "passive" components? Why not add a comparator or a precision reset chip (comparator + reference)?

Comment: Define "passive"?

Comment: @Trevor_G ....passive as in not active. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_component

Comment: @JackCreasey ;) well.. I know that.. and YOU know that.... but ....

Comment: You would have to do the math with the voltage threshold limits for your particular micro.. but since logic signals typically have a wide hysteresis percentage I would doubt you will be able to get it to work the way you imagine.

Comment: Many modern 1.8V µC have an analog comperator peripherial, which is simpler than adc. I'd use that when available.

Comment: @Trevor_G By Passives I meant resistors and capacitors. If that guideline is removed, what is your suggested answer?

Comment: WHat does "LOW for >4.2V HIGH for 5V" MEAN!... those are not mutually exclusive. and plus or minus WHAT?

Comment: @Trevor_G That was a typo. Typed the wrong signal. Fixed it. Below 4.3V has absolutely to be LOW.

Comment: @AmiguelS that's better though you really need to know Low below 4.2 high above some number... perhaps 4.5V

Comment: It would be *really really* useful to know which micro you are using...!

Comment: Your question is still incomplete. What is to happen if the signal is 4.6 V, for example? Please re-read it from the point of view of someone who has no idea what your end goal is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple RC network.

1. Short the capacitor using the GPIO pin
2. Turn the GPIO to input
3. Measure the time for the input to reach a '1'
4. Use the RC time constant to calculate the input voltage

Temperature variation of the GPIO pin threshold is up to you to discover, but hysteresis does not enter into it. You are only using the positive threshold value.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0XZIY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to be able to trigger interrupts from this signal. Polling does not fit my use case.

Comment: @AmiguelS you need to edit and put that in the question. Creeping requirement question are really frowned on here.

Comment: If you run a regular timer tick then you don't need to spin waiting for the threshold to be crossed. In any case you could have interrupt enabled on the GPIO pin and simply service that as the threshold ....either will work but you need a timer tick.

Comment: @Trevor_G I just added that, sorry. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: This will work, though the threshold level tolerance itself may be too high. However, at 1.8V it can't be THAT bad. It depends on how accurate the OP needs the 4.2V to be.

Answer (score 0):

Use a voltage supervisor chip with open collector output + pull-up reststor to be compatible with the uC 1.8 supply. See some sugestions from [Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/power-management/supervisor-reset-ic/products.html#p790typ=4.38&p2059=Active-low)